# Represent following fact in prolog

Tags: prolog

I am learning prolog. I am wondering about how can i represent following fact in prolog?

"There are 300 miles between someCityA and someCityB".
Anyone help please.I have searched for it enough but cant find solution to my specific problem.

Comment: Please do not edit in an answer into your question. If you want to answer your own question, go to the answer box below and post your own answer. You can even accept your own answer as the answer that helped you the most. This structure keeps StackOverflow clean.

Comment: `distance_between_cities(someCityA, someCityB, 300).` ?

Comment: yes I did it the same way, long before.Anyway, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prolog allows to represent knowledge by facts and rules. A
fact and a rule have the following format:

```
  A :- A1, .., An
```

Where A, A1, .., An are so called literals. If n=0 then its
a fact, if n>0 then its a rule.

A literal has the folllowing syntax, name is the predicate name
and the terms are the arguments of the predicate:

```
  literal = atom [ "(" term { "," term } ].
```

Knowledge respresentation is an art in itself. There can be
many requirements to the representation, which can force it
to have a certain form.

But you can think as a literal as an excel sheet that is used
to hold a table. The columns that describe the column names are
not entered into Prolog as facts and rules, but you can use
Prolog [comments](http://arxiv.org/abs/0911.2899) to enter the column names, such as:

```
  % distance_between_cities(Atom, Atom, Float)
```

Or more specific:

```
  % distance_between_cities(CityId, CityId, DistanceMiles)
```

After the first comment, you just enter the facts:

```
  distance_between_cities('New York, US','Los Angeles, US',2443.85).
  distance_between_cities('New York, US','San Francisco, US',2563.89).
  distance_between_cities('Los Angeles, US','San Francisco, US',347.18).
```

Different predicate names can name different excel sheets 
so to speak. Some prolog systems even have [CSV](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=csv) interfaces.

Bye